# Error showing staff distribution of a company

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables: [BRANCH_T] and [EMPLOYEE_T].

BRANCH_T contain branch_id and manager_emp_id(foreign key).

In EMPLOYEE_T contain emp_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname, emp_position, emp_gender and branch_id(foreign key).

I wanted to show branch_id, manager name for each branch, total number of supervisors, total number of male employees and total number of female employees.

Below is my code:

```
SELECT b.bch_id AS 'BRANCH NUMBER',
(CASE WHEN emp_position = 'M' 
THEN emp_fname + ' ' + emp_lname ELSE '-' END) AS 'MANAGER NAME',
SUM (CASE WHEN e.emp_position = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL NUMBER OF SUPERVISOR',
SUM (CASE WHEN e.emp_gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL MALE EMPPLOYEES',
SUM (CASE WHEN e.emp_gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL FEMALE EMPLOYEES'
FROM EMPLOYEE_T e, BRANCH_T b
WHERE b.bch_id = e.bch_id
GROUP BY b.bch_id, e.emp_fname, e.emp_lname, e.emp_gender, e.emp_position
```

This is the generated result.

```
+---------------+--------------+-----------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
| branch number | manager name | total number of supervisors | total male employees | total female employees |
+---------------+--------------+-----------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
| B001          | EMILIA MOANA |                           0 |                    0 |                      1 |
| B001          | -            |                           1 |                    1 |                      0 |
| B001          | -            |                           0 |                    0 |                      1 |
| B002          | MARCUS HOW   |                           1 |                    0 |                      1 |
+---------------+--------------+-----------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
```

I tried another code, but it got error and cannot be executed.

```
SELECT  b.bch_id AS 'BRANCH NUMBER',
b.mng_emp_id AS 'MANAGER ID',
(SELECT e.emp_fname + ' ' + e.emp_lname
FROM EMPLOYEE_T e, BRANCH_T b
WHERE   b.mng_emp_id = e.emp_id and
b.bch_id = e.bch_id
group by e.emp_fname, e.emp_lname, e.bch_id) AS 'MANAGER NAME',
SUM (CASE WHEN e.emp_position = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'NUMBER OF SUPERVISOR',
SUM (CASE WHEN e.emp_gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'NUMBER OF MALE EMPLOYEES',
SUM (CASE WHEN e.emp_gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'NUMBER OF FEMALE EMPLOYEES'
FROM EMPLOYEE_T e, BRANCH_T b
WHERE   e.bch_id = b.bch_id
GROUP BY b.bch_id, b.mng_emp_id, e.emp_position, e.emp_gender
```

Error code:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

What I want to show is like this:

```
+---------------+--------------+-----------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
| branch number | manager name | total number of supervisors | total male employees | total female employees |
+---------------+--------------+-----------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
| B001          | EMILIA MOANA |                           1 |                    1 |                      2 |
| B002          | MARCUS HOW   |                           1 |                    2 |                      1 |
| B003          | ELINA YEAN   |                           1 |                    1 |                      1 |
+---------------+--------------+-----------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
```

Please help. Thank you.

----------------UPDATE----------------

I get to retrieve the numbers of supervisors, male and female employees at each branch successfully, but i was only able to get the mng_emp_id out from BRANCH_T.

```
SELECT  b.bch_id AS 'BRANCH NUMBER',
b.mng_emp_id AS 'MANAGER ID',
SUM (CASE WHEN e.emp_position = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'NUMBER OF SUPERVISOR',
SUM (CASE WHEN e.emp_gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'NUMBER OF MALE EMPLOYEES',
SUM (CASE WHEN e.emp_gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'NUMBER OF FEMALE EMPLOYEES'
FROM EMPLOYEE_T e, BRANCH_T b
WHERE   e.bch_id = b.bch_id
GROUP BY b.bch_id, b.mng_emp_id
```

The mng_emp_id is part of the emp_id.

BRANCH_T:

```
+--------+------------+
| BCH_ID | MNG_EMP_ID |
+--------+------------+
| B001   | EM001      |
| B002   | EM002      |
| B003   | EM003      |
+--------+------------+
```

EMPLOYEE_T:

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| EMP_ID | EMP_FNAME | EMP_LNAME | BCH_ID |
+--------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| EM001  | A         | Z         | B001   |
| EM002  | B         | Y         | B002   |
| EM003  | C         | X         | B003   |
| ES001  | D         | W         | B001   |
| ET001  | E         | V         | B002   |
+--------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: as the error suggests.. the subquery should only return 1 column and 1 row.

Comment: This entirely depends on what your data looks like. If, for example, your branches can only have a single manager, then you just need to group by the bch_id (no other fields) - your manager will be `max(case when emp_position = 'm' then emp_fname + ' ' + emp_lname end)` and you can just do the regular sums for the others. If, however, you can have multiple managers in a branch with different employees under each manager, then you might need to figure out a way to do a recursive query.